# Input currency format react redux form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-form

I'm using Redux-Form (https://github.com/redux-form/redux-form) for my ReactJs application.There is a field to show input value as a currency.

when user type **24000** , i want to show it on text field as **24,000**

Then i tried it as bellow

```
const currencyFormatter = value => 
    value && 
    new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', {
        maximumSignificantDigits: 3
    }).format(value)

  renderField(field) {
        const { meta: { touched, error } } = field;
        const className = `form-group ${touched && error ? "has-danger" : ""}`;
        return (
            <div className={className}>
                <label for={field.name}>{field.label}</label>
                <input className="form-control"
                    type={field.type || 'tel'}
                    name={field.name}
                    disabled={field.disabled}
                    {...field.input}
                    placeholder={field.placeholder}
                />
                <p className="text-danger mb-0">{touched ? error : ""}</p>
            </div>
        )
    }

<Field 
component={this.renderField} 
normalize={currencyFormatter}
name="credit" type="number" />
```

But i'm getting warring in my browser console

> react-dom.development.js:2427 The specified value "24,000" is not a
>   valid number. The value must match to the following regular
>   expression: -?(\d+|\d+.\d+|.\d+)([eE][-+]?\d+)?